# In tinkerpop gremlin, how do I search on properties of a vertex where there is a list of objects?

Tags: node.js, gremlin, tinkerpop

I have a vertex with the label `MyVertex` that has the following properties

```
{
  text: "hello world",
  indicator: {
    code: [
      {
        unit: "thing",
        val: "123"
      },
      {
        unit: "other",
        val: "456"
      }
    ],
    text: "test"
  }
}
```

How do find all vertices that have a certain `val` in the `code` array?

I am using gremlin-node.

I have tried queries such as the following but to no avail.

```
g.V()
 .hasLabel('MyVertex')
 .properties('indicator')
 .unfold()
 .has('val', '123')
 .toList()
```

To create this graph in gremlin-node, I run the following

```
const data = {
    text: 'hello world',
    indicator: {
        code: [
            {
                unit: 'thing',
                val: '123',
            },
            {
                unit: 'other',
                val: '456',
            },
        ],
        text: 'test',
    },
};

const v = g.addV('MyVertex');

for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(data)) {
    v.property(key, val);
}

v.next();
```

Comment: can you supply a script to create a small example graph?

Comment: Sure! I edited the original post.

Comment: I don't think you can look at the 'val' value this way, from what I know gremlin support only 1 level of meta property. so all the object saved inside of the 'indicator' doesn't save as vertex property, therefore you cannot filter by them. I think you should consider separating your data into several connected vertexes. also not all graph DB support meta properties (like Neptune).

Comment: @noam621 Thanks for the response. What are meta properties in this context? I believe you can save complex objects as vertex properties. At least I am able to save this structure and query it again and inspect the Map `indicator`, and sub-maps of `code`.

Comment: You can get the second and third level properties. But they aren't indexed. So I don't think that you be able to do any gremlin steps on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do this:

```
gremlin> g.addV('myvertex').property('text','hello world').property('indicator',[code:[[unit:'thing',val:123],[unit:'other',val:456]],text:'test']).iterate()
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('myvertex').
......1>   filter(values('indicator').
......2>          select('code').
......3>          unfold().
......4>          select('val').is(12))
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('myvertex').
......1>   filter(values('indicator').
......2>          select('code').
......3>          unfold().
......4>          select('val').is(123))
==>v[0]
```

Just note that:

1. I imagine that you're currently just using TinkerGraph which can support these sorts of complex (arbitrary) property values. A good many graphs won't allow that so just be aware that you are getting locked into a subset of graph systems by modelling this way.
2. Not even TinkerGraph allows indexing of this query so it is a full graph scan which means it will be expensive. This may not be the worst query on TinkerGraph assuming you can limit the initial vertex search space properly with an index - vertex label may not be enough.

I'd largely recommend that you look into a less hierarchical model for storing this sort of data if you need to search on it.

Comment: Thanks! This is great information and will help me make decisions in how I want to store my data.